# Assign all records of a user 'high' or 'low' if the rank 1 record qualifies for high MySQL

Tags: mysql, mariadb, record, rank

I have a table with several USERid, and I have ranked them using partition by user id and order by date. Now I want to do this: if the first record (ie rank 1 record) of the user has a '100x' in speed I create a column that has 'high' for all records of this user, else 'low' for all records of a user. How can I do that in mysql?

| USERid | Date. | rank. | speed |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1a | some date. | 1 | 90x |
| 1a | some date. | 2 | 15x. |
| 2b | some date. | 1 | 100x |
| 2b | some date. | 3 | 30x |
| 1c | some date. | 1 | 100x |
| 1c | some date. | 2 | 3x. |

And I want something like this:

| USERid | Date. | rank. | speed | rating |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1a | some date. | 1 | 90x | low. |
| 1a | some date. | 2 | 100x | low. |
| 2b | some date. | 1 | 100x | high. |
| 2b | some date. | 3 | 30x | high. |
| 1c | some date. | 1 | 100x | high. |
| 1c | some date. | 2 | 3x. | high. |

(Ignore the dots)

Answer (score 0):

test this:

```sql
SELECT t1.*, 
       CASE WHEN t2.userid 
            THEN 'high' 
            ELSE 'low' 
            END rating
FROM table t1
LEFT JOIN ( SELECT 
            FROM table t2
            WHERE `rank` = 1
              AND speed = '100x' ) t3 USING (userid);
```

or this

```sql
SELECT t1.*,
       CASE WHEN EXISTS ( SELECT NULL
                          FROM table t2
                          WHERE t1.userid = t2.userid
                             AND `rank` = 1
                             AND speed = '100x )
            THEN 'high'
            ELSE 'low' 
            END rating
FROM table t1;
```

Comment: But what if the first table is a cte?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `FIRST_VALUE()` window function:

```
SELECT *,
       CASE 
         WHEN FIRST_VALUE(speed) OVER (PARTITION BY USERid ORDER BY date) = '100x' -- or ORDER BY `rank`
           THEN 'high' 
         ELSE 'low' 
       END rating
FROM tablename
```